How to remove the arrow from ttk.Menubutton (+ bonusquestion)
I want to style a menubar and I want to remove the menubutton-arrows. I know, I could color them in the same color as the background, but then I also have to do that for any other state (hovering, etc.). It would be far easier to just disable it using style.configure...
For reference, this is the style I am currently using:
class Styles:
    
    @staticmethod
    def apply_theme():
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.theme_use('clam')

    @staticmethod
    def style_menubar(style: ttk.Style):
        background_color = "#130E0B"
        
        style.configure("Menubar.TFrame", 
                        background=background_color)
        
        style.configure("Menu.TMenubutton", 
                        arrowcolor=background_color, 
                        background=background_color,
                        foreground="#EDEDED",
                        activebackground="#5C5C5C", 
                        relief='flat')

and the menubar class:
class Menubar(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        Styles.style_menubar(ttk.Style())
                
        self.configure(style="Menubar.TFrame")
        self.create_menubar(parent)
    
    def create_menubar(self, root):
        # Create the File menubutton
        file_menubutton = ttk.Menubutton(self, text="File", style="Menu.TMenubutton")
        file_menu = Menu(file_menubutton, tearoff=0)
        file_menu.add_command(label="New")
        file_menu.add_command(label="Open")
        file_menu.add_command(label="Save")
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
        file_menubutton["menu"] = file_menu
        file_menubutton.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.NONE)

        # Additional buttons...


Additional question
How do I make the width of the menubuttons smaller? Currently, there is the text, then a large gap, then the menubutton. Using padding or spacing doesn't help. This would be necessary anyways, when simply recoloring the arrow.
I tried using ipadx, fill=tk.NONE; padding=(0,0), spacing3=0 and activeindicatoron = 0

Unfortunately, tkinter does not provide a direct way to disable the arrows entirely through the style.configure method.
So, the best method is to just do as you said.
def style_menubar(style: ttk.Style):
    background_color = "#130E0B"
    
    style.configure("Menubar.TFrame", 
                    background=background_color)
    
    style.configure("Menu.TMenubutton", 
                    arrowcolor=background_color,  # Same as background to "hide" it
                    background=background_color,
                    foreground="#EDEDED",
                    activebackground="#5C5C5C", 
                    relief='flat',
                    compound="left") #Make it less noticeable

I am including this snippet just because.
Also, to reduce the width, you can use the anchor method -
padding=(0, 0),  # Remove internal padding
                    width=10,  # Set fixed width
                    anchor="center")  # Center text within the button

Add this to style.configure

Thank you, the anchoring was a great idea. I also found out, that you can go into the negative with the padding, so I added these lines to the style.configure:
padding=(-10,0,-25,0),
spacing3=0,

Not entirely sure if that spacing3 is doing much, though...
I also found style.map works great at controlling the different states so I'm using that instead of activebackground.
But I suppose that is as far as I can get with ttk. Will try to get ttkbootstrap to work, since they replaced and added more widgets.

This will only work for Tk rendered themes. For the Windows or Mac themes that use native theme engines you should amend the layout for the TMenubutton style to remove the dropdown element.  style.layout('TMenubutton', style.layout('TMenubutton')[1]) should do it as the layout has 2 toplevel components on windows and the second is the button part. The layout might vary per theme however.

There is a configure option called 'arrowsize' for the Menubutton, if set to zero, the arrow disappears. Then you don't need to bother with the color. At least it works when using style themes 'alt' and 'clam', for 'classic' and 'default' the options are called 'indicatorwidth' and 'indicatorheight'.
